# Why does my 9-patch Android splash screen have a black rectangle in the middle of it?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, splash-screen, nine-patch

I'm trying to use a 9-patch image as a splash screen, but I get a weird artefact when doing so.

I use the following style on the activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

This references the following drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/splash_background" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <nine-patch 
            android:src="@drawable/test_splash" 
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The [9-patch image](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnyysDdGdDYSlE74PoiDJKgmwHo7) has two scalable vertical regions---above and below "Middle". There is no horizontal scaling set.

[image: 9-patch image]

What this ends up giving me is

[image: bad screenshot]

Where is that black bar 3/4 of the way down coming from?

Comment: Could it be the black tag you set on a 9-patch's border to indicate which is the part that should be stretched?

Comment: It could be, but I don't see why the upper one would have the same effect. And, I only have 1 pixel, so it should be treated as the 9-patch marking.

Comment: Perhaps the upper mark is saying that the vertical mark is what should be extended. How do you see it if you edit the file?

Comment: The upper mark is one pixel in, on the top row. If it's saying it should be extended, then I'm wondering why it is also extending vertically too.

Comment: Seems like it could be something to do with the marks, but I'm stumped as to what or why.

Comment: The black pixels in the 1st top row indicate what pixels are extendended in width (the vertical projection of that or those pixels is what gest extended in width). Check if the pixel you mentions is vertically on top of the black pixel on the left.

Comment: No. It's not on the corner, it's at (0, 1) [v, h]. The pixel that is marking the vertical scale is at (k, 0).

Comment: Actually. Sorry, there's *no* pixels on the top row---it's all transparent. I've been trying so many combinations I forget the one I used here.

Comment: So nothing should be stretching horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. After scrubbing thru all of my splash.9.png files looking for the problem, I retreated and tried one that worked fine in another app. It produced the same artifact.

It seems the issue is with the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. Try this instead:

```
  <style name="splashscreen" parent="android:Theme">
```

It doesn't look exactly the same around the title bar and such, but it looks like a splash screen.

Comment: This caused some weird other bars to show up for me (using Flutter). `android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` did the trick however (in `android/app/src/main/res/styles` in the `LaunchTheme` style).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Xamarin (I use Titanium), but I had this exact problem when I didn't provide a padding box (the black pixels on the right and bottom).  I fixed it by filling the padding lines with black.